# How to deal with static variables in Wildfly module jar used by multiple war Applications

Tags: jakarta-ee, wildfly, classloader

I want to use a library jar in multiple WAR applications which are bundled in one EAR. Therefore I have added this jar as a module dependency in the jboss-deployment-structure.xml of the EAR.

The issue is that the library has static variables (standard Singleton pattern with POJOs and caches) which need to be isolated between the applications. As the library is included as module dependency for every war application the same class instance (and therefore the same static variable) is used.

```
EAR structure:
|-- META-INF
|   |-- jboss-deployment-structure.xml
|-- WAR A
|-- WAR B
|-- WAR ...
```

Event with having the module referenced in the sub-deployment section jboss-deployment-structure.xml I guess there's still the ModuleClassloader used instead of the WarClassloader:

```
<jboss-deployment-structure>
    <deployment>
        <dependencies>
            ...
        </dependencies>
    </deployment>
    <sub-deployment name="TEST001_Wildfly.war">
        <dependencies>
            <module name="com.shared.lib" />
        </dependencies>
    </sub-deployment>
    <sub-deployment name="TEST002_Wildfly.war">
        <dependencies>
            <module name="com.shared.lib" />
        </dependencies>
    </sub-deployment>
</jboss-deployment-structure>
```

How can the shared library module jar be referenced / used in any war application so that the class instance with static variables is NOT shared between them?

Comment: You'd have to put the lib in each WAR if you don't want static variables shared.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. That's bad as the library is used by many WARs and I would have wanted to manage it's version at one place.

Comment: That's how static variables work :) The only way to avoid static variables from being shared is to ensure they are on another class loader.

Comment: Exactly that's what I have to get used to as I'm coming from Websphere Traditional where a shared library is loaded by each applications class loader.