# How does static variable have different behavior in a module in Wildfly/JBoss?

Tags: java, module, static, jboss, wildfly

In Wildfly/JBoss, if you have a static variable defined in a .jar file within a module, you will get a shared instance of that variable across all .wars that use that jar from that module.  However, if you use a static variable from a .jar that's within each .war, then each application (.war) gets their own instance of that variable.

This is discussed in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54986889/how-to-deal-with-static-variables-in-wildfly-module-jar-used-by-multiple-war-app), and I have also verified this with RedHat, and have actually made use of this different behavior to my benefit, although I haven't gotten an explanation of how/why that works.

What is the actual mechanism that makes this possible?  When you google how a Java static variable works, you find discussion about how there's a single instance (and it implies across the JVM), but clearly that's not the case because I can get different behavior within the same JVM but in different .war applications in the JVM.  So what is actually happening here to explain the difference in behavior?

Comment: `What is the actual mechanism that makes this possible?` It's a class loader.  Not sure if this is the best source, but it'll get you started: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11035_01/wls100/programming/classloading.html

Comment: I wish I could remember all the resources I used to learn this but basically a class loader is often used to partition a space of Java classes.  If you have application A that uses SomeClass, and application B that also uses that class, often you want to completely isolate these two applications and their classes so they don't interact at all.  That includes not sharing class (global) variables, so class loaders are used to accomplish that partitioning.

Comment: Here's a resource from IBM that also talks about class loading in a WAR file. https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/was-nd/8.5.5?topic=loading-class-loaders